# Asserting the last record in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm trying to assert that the last record did not get deleted in rails model unit test. I raise an exception if the record.count.one? is true. Initially there are two records.

Edited:
There is a user story that says you can delete the users.
You cannot delete the user that you are logged in with. (functional test)
You cannot delete the last user. (unit test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is:

```
  test "verify cannot destroy last user" do
    assert_raise(RuntimeError) {
      User.find(:all).select {|u| u.destroy} }
    assert_equal 1, User.count
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my literal translation of what you are asking (I think):

```
last_user = User.last
...
assert_equal last_user, User.last
```

Here's more traditional test code that is a bit less fragile:

```
assert_difference('User.count',-1) do
  ...
end
```

(But Gutzofter may actually be onto what you're looking for.)

Comment: Gutzofter is the one looking for it ;)